# Wordpress website content not updating unless I am logged in

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I installed the Content Control plugin, and afterwards it worked (I used it for just one page, which wasn't the Home page), but some content, such as some sections and the footer, didn't update unless I was logged in. I tried clearing my cache and deleting the plugin, but the problem persists. Also the content shows if I type [www.mywebsite.com/home](http://www.mywebsite.com/home).  [[image: Home Logged in][1]][image: Home Logged out][image: Footer Logged in][image: Footer Logged out]

Answer (score 1):

This seems totally cache issue, try to check in private window to get assure. Try following.

1. clear cache
2. purge js and css

Comment: if not successful, try to check in console

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the sourcecode i see this

```
<!-- This website is like a Rocket, isn't it? Performance optimized by WP Rocket. Learn more: https://wp-rocket.me - Debug: cached@1629784693 -->
```

Normally these caching plugins work in a way that they deliver a static HTML page for not logged in users.

So when you log in, for example as admin, you usually get a non-cached page.

In the settings you can set the cache lifespan:

more about this here: https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/78-how-often-is-the-cache-updated